# Trying to Convert Binary Search Tree to Array (returns Null)

Tags: java, arrays, binary-search-tree, binary-search, inorder

I want to convert my binary search tree into array (using in order traversal).

to Do this I have 3 methods.

**Issue: java.lang.NullPointerException in the method 1 System.out.print() call. However returns 4 elements successfully (2 are null hence this error but why?!)**

**Class (1 main) method 1 (call method)**

```
 public void top() {
    array[] unsortedList = this.bookList.returnBSTAsArray(6); // 6 is the number of nodes in tree
     for (Book book: unsortedList) {
         System.out.println("--> Title: " + book.title());
     }
```

**class (2) method 2**

```
// traverse BST in order and return an array of books 
public Book[] returnBSTAsArray(int totalLength) {
    Book[] list = new Book[totalLength];
    int index = 0;

    storeInOrder(this.root, list, index);  // root is node accessible to this class

    return list;
}
```

**Class (2) method 3 - the interesting method that does the in order traverse**

```
 private Book[] storeInOrder(Node root, Book[] array, int index) {
        if (root == null)
            return null;
        storeInOrder(root.leftChild, array, index);
        array[index++] = root.movie;
        storeInOrder(root.rightChild, array, index);

        return array;
    }
```

Comment: Could you put the code of BST

Comment: Also, do you want to retrieve in the insertion order to BST?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java is a "pass by value" language. Hence (generaly speaking), any change to an argument value in a function won't be visible by the caller.

The `storeInOrder` function is the problem. It is written as if changes to the `index` arg will be visible by the caller.

This assumption is incorrect.

Moreover, it returns the array, but as an array is indeed a reference, it is not changed in the method (but it CONTENT is), hence there is no need to return the array as a result.

Hence, a better profile would be for `storeInOrder` to take and return the index of the first available cell in the array.

```
/**
 * insert the elements of the bst (denoted by root) into array,
 * starting at index (the first available position in array) and
 * returns the first available position after insertion)
 * pre-conditions : 
 *    - root is a bst containing n elements
 *    - array contains enough available cells
 *    - index = i0
 * post-conditions
 *    - tree is unchanged
 *    - array[i0..i0+n-1] contains elements of the bst
 *    - functions returns i0+n
 */
private int storeInOrder(Node root, Book[] array, int index) {
    if (root == null)
        return index;
    // then call on left, add root, call on right...
    int i = storeInOrder(root.leftChild, array, index);
    array[i] = root.movie;
    return storeInOrder(root.rightChild, array, i+1);
}
```

NOTA: if you want the array in Book's order, just change the order of the recursive calls to get the prefix left right traversal.

Comment: If you don't mind elaborating "take and return the index of the first available cell in the array." and " then call on left, add root, call on right.." - I need access to the node, if i return the index it is of know use to me though? Perhaps I'm missing something?

Comment: One cannot write a correct recursive function if its specification is unclear. Try to state the spec of your solution and you'll immediately see that it will not work. I will add the spec to my version and you'll be able to use it in its implementation.

Comment: With this explicit spec, you'll see that for a non empty tree, you will be inserting the elements on the left at position index..index+nl-1, the root at index+nl and the elements on the right at index+nl+1..index+nl+nr+1 (with nl being the # of left elements and nr the # of right elements). The first call will return (index+nl). Similarly, if you pass index+nl+1 to the second call it will given you back index+nl+nr+1.

Comment: I have to say still learning but I've never seen returning a method call:         return storeInOrder(root.rightChild, array, i+1);   Didn't think returning anything is required in a recursion (its in a call stack?) let alone a method call ? Thanks

Comment: return is necessary because the specification asks the method to return the insertion's end index

Answer (score 0):

You can use accomplish by keep tracking the index of each element to add it back to the result array

```
  static class BST {

        private class Node {
            private Integer key;
            private Node left, right;
            private int index;

            public Node(Integer key, int index) {
                this.key = key;
                this.index = index;
            }
        }

        private Node root;
        private int size = 0;

        public void put(int[] arr) {
            if (size >= arr.length)
                return;
            root = put(root, arr[size], size);
            size++;
            put(arr);
        }

        private Node put(Node node, int key, int index) {
            if (node == null)
                return new Node(key, index);
            int cmp = Integer.valueOf(key).compareTo(node.key);
            if (cmp < 0)
                node.left = put(node.left, key, index);
            else if (cmp > 0)
                node.right = put(node.right, key, index);
            else
                node.key = key;
            return node;
        }

        public int size() {
            return size;
        }

        public int[] keys() {
            int[] result = new int[size];
            get(root, result, 0);
            return result;
        }

        public void get(Node node, int[] result, int i) {
            if (i >= result.length || node == null)
                return;
            result[node.index] = node.key;
            get(node.left, result, ++i);
            get(node.right, result, ++i);
        }
    }
```

, main

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BST bst = new BST();
        bst.put(new int[] { 10, 20, 5, 40, 1, 60, -10, 0 });

        for (int num : bst.keys()) {
            System.out.print(num + " ");
        }
    }
```

, output

```
10 20 5 40 1 60
```